# How to set screen resolution in PhantomJS with python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

How to set screen resolution in PhantomJS? I need to change exactly screen resolution not window size.

Window size != screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the similar situation a couple of days ago. Browsed through a lot of discussion forums/discussions. The one suggestion I got regarding window resizing is this[link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/585), you have to

`beforeEach(function() { browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024); });`

Having said that, this solution didn't serve my purpose. I had to perform some tricky measures.

Let me know if it works else I will suggest you more options.

Comment: Thanks! But I think it will set window size not screen resolution. Anyway this solution unsuitable for me because i'm using python and I need to change exactly screen resolution.

Comment: @marklevin though in the subject you have mentioned about screen resolution but I can see in your code you are trying to fix the screen height & width. Hence was my answer. Thanks.